# ServiceStack Serialization Hook

Tags: serialization, hook, servicestack

Is there a hook in ServiceStack which will give me access to the serialized service response object and the http response?

Specifically, I want to add a hash of the serialized response object to the http headers which the client will use to verify the content.

An `IHasResponseFilter` implementation is almost right, but the service response hasn't been serialized and I want to avoid duplicating that work.